# Why is my 2009 Macbook's fan turning on and off during sleep?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, sleep-wake, temperature, console

I'm running a 2009 13in Macbook running OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 with a USB keyboard attached.

I'm noticing often that, while my macbook is closed. The fan turns on and off repeatedly and is hot. It's been happening for a long time now, though I'm just now deciding to consider that it's something to look into more. Can anyone help me to figure this out? I don't understand what any of the information means when I read the logs; I have never dived that deep into the computer world. From a few searches, I found that this might be related to Watchdog Daemon? When I first saw that I thought my computer was getting hacked. Same with things like:

```
Attempted to remove an observer when not observing
```

I'm running a 2009 13in Macbook running OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 with a USB keyboard attached.

Here are some system logs:

FAN TURNS ON:

```
6/5/17 5:41:20.848 PM watchdogd[170]: [watchdog_daemon] @(         pm_callback) - ref=0x0 msg_type=0xe0000300 msg=0x0
6/5/17 5:41:20.848 PM sharingd[390]: 17:41:20.848 : Starting AirDrop server for user 501 on wake
6/5/17 5:41:20.852 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:41:20.850864 PM [AirPlay] Power: SystemHasPoweredOn
6/5/17 5:41:20.853 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:41:20.852551 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client starting to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
6/5/17 5:41:20.853 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:41:20.852842 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client stopping to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
6/5/17 5:41:20.853 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:41:20.852998 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client starting to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
6/5/17 5:41:20.864 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:41:20.864213 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client started to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
6/5/17 5:41:20.864 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:41:20.864423 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client stopped to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
6/5/17 5:41:20.865 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:41:20.864575 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client started to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
6/5/17 5:41:20.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 1
6/5/17 5:41:20.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 1
6/5/17 5:41:20.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 1
6/5/17 5:41:31.582 PM watchdogd[170]: [watchdog_daemon] @(         pm_callback) - ref=0x0 msg_type=0xe0000280 msg=0x2d1e0006
6/5/17 5:41:31.582 PM watchdogd[170]: [watchdog_daemon] @(    wd_daemon_thread) - events buffer: 99160r455908 99170s455908 99198r456273 99209s456273 99236r456621 99247s456621 99275r456976 99286s456976 99314r457364 99324s457364 99352r457732 99363s457732 99391r458070 99402s458070 99432r458411 99443s458411 99474r458768 99484s458768 99512r459115 99523s459115 99550r459450 99561s459450 99589r459894 99599s459894 99627r460243 99638s460243 99666r460601 99677s460601 99704r460955 99715s460955 99746r461311 99757s461311 
6/5/17 5:41:31.586 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:41:31.585925 PM [AirPlay] Power: SystemWillSleep
6/5/17 5:41:31.586 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:41:31.586136 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client stopping to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
6/5/17 5:41:31.586 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:41:31.586306 PM [AirPlay] BTLE discovery removing all devices
6/5/17 5:41:31.589 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:41:31.589150 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client stopped to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
6/5/17 5:41:33.714 PM WindowServer[132]: device_generate_desktop_screenshot: authw 0x7fea69ce7d80(2000), shield 0x7fea69dafef0(2001)
6/5/17 5:41:33.730 PM WindowServer[132]: device_generate_lock_screen_screenshot: authw 0x7fea69ce7d80(2000)[0, 0, 1280, 800] shield 0x7fea69dafef0(2001), dev [1280,800]
6/5/17 5:41:33.855 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.user.501) Service "com.apple.xpc.launchd.unmanaged.loginwindow.85" tried to hijack endpoint "com.apple.tsm.uiserver" from owner: com.apple.SystemUIServer.agent
6/5/17 5:41:33.855 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.user.501) Service "com.apple.xpc.launchd.unmanaged.loginwindow.85" tried to hijack endpoint "com.apple.tsm.uiserver" from owner: com.apple.SystemUIServer.agent
6/5/17 5:41:35.000 PM kernel[0]: PM response took 2770 ms (47, powerd)
6/5/17 5:41:35.000 PM kernel[0]: [0x9c4808000, 0x19000000]
6/5/17 5:41:35.000 PM kernel[0]: [0xa0c811000, 0x27000000]
6/5/17 5:41:35.000 PM kernel[0]: [0x0, 0x0]
6/5/17 5:41:35.000 PM kernel[0]: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Sleep 
6/5/17 5:41:35.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate image path: /var/vm/sleepimage
6/5/17 5:41:35.000 PM kernel[0]: efi pagecount 541
6/5/17 5:41:35.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall(preflight 1) start 0xffffff804c268000, 0xffffff804c369000
6/5/17 5:41:35.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall time: 110 ms
6/5/17 5:41:35.000 PM kernel[0]: pages 443998, wire 76087, act 157210, inact 27945, cleaned 1 spec 5, zf 27771, throt 0, compr 56403, xpmapped 28240
6/5/17 5:41:35.000 PM kernel[0]: could discard act 13849 inact 83414 purgeable 322 spec 966 cleaned 25
6/5/17 5:41:35.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall preflight pageCount 345422 est comp 61 setfile 934281216 min 1073741824
6/5/17 5:41:35.000 PM kernel[0]: [0x9c4808000, 0x19000000]
6/5/17 5:41:35.000 PM kernel[0]: [0xa0c811000, 0x27000000]
6/5/17 5:41:35.000 PM kernel[0]: [0x0, 0x0]
6/5/17 5:41:35.000 PM kernel[0]: kern_open_file_for_direct_io(0) took 0 ms
6/5/17 5:41:35.000 PM kernel[0]: Opened file /var/vm/sleepimage, size 1073741824, partition base 0x0, maxio 2000000 ssd 0
6/5/17 5:41:35.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate image major 1, minor 0, blocksize 4096, pollers 5
6/5/17 5:41:35.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_alloc_pages act 171313, inact 139222, anon 40661, throt 0, spec 972, wire 76254, wireinit 133356
6/5/17 5:41:35.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_setup(0) took 0 ms
6/5/17 5:41:35.000 PM kernel[0]: 00000000  00000020  NVEthernet::setLinkStatus - not Active
6/5/17 5:41:35.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 1
6/5/17 5:41:55.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall(preflight 0) start 0xffffff804c268000, 0xffffff804c369000
6/5/17 5:41:55.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall time: 115 ms
6/5/17 5:41:55.000 PM kernel[0]: pages 445650, wire 77720, act 157225, inact 27945, cleaned 2 spec 6, zf 27770, throt 0, compr 56403, xpmapped 28240
6/5/17 5:41:55.000 PM kernel[0]: could discard act 13852 inact 83415 purgeable 322 spec 966 cleaned 24
6/5/17 5:41:55.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall found pageCount 347071
6/5/17 5:41:55.000 PM kernel[0]: IOHibernatePollerOpen, ml_get_interrupts_enabled 0
6/5/17 5:41:55.000 PM kernel[0]: IOHibernatePollerOpen(0)
6/5/17 5:41:55.000 PM kernel[0]: encryptStart 14010
6/5/17 5:41:55.000 PM kernel[0]: bitmap_size 0xe048, previewSize 0x401000, writing 344793 pages @ 0x423058
6/5/17 5:41:55.000 PM kernel[0]: encryptEnd 5117800
6/5/17 5:41:55.000 PM kernel[0]: image1Size 0x7d79000, encryptStart1 0x14010, End1 0x5117800
6/5/17 5:41:55.000 PM kernel[0]: encryptStart 7d79000
6/5/17 5:41:55.000 PM kernel[0]: encryptEnd 34a4ee00
6/5/17 5:41:55.000 PM kernel[0]: PMStats: Hibernate write took 19219 ms
6/5/17 5:41:55.000 PM kernel[0]: all time: 19219 ms, comp bytes: 1412554752 time: 2003 ms 672 Mb/s, crypt bytes: 836605424 time: 5716 ms 139 Mb/s, 
6/5/17 5:41:55.000 PM kernel[0]: image 883224576 (82%), uncompressed 1412554752 (344862), compressed 876338368 (62%), sum1 81298092, sum2 48930a3
6/5/17 5:41:55.000 PM kernel[0]: zeroPageCount 18363, wiredPagesEncrypted 48305, wiredPagesClear 27206, dirtyPagesEncrypted 269351
6/5/17 5:41:55.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_write_image done(0)
6/5/17 5:41:55.000 PM kernel[0]: sleep
6/5/17 5:41:55.000 PM kernel[0]: Wake reason: OHC1
6/5/17 5:41:55.955 PM loginwindow[85]: CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.
```

FAN TURNS OFF:

```
6/5/17 5:41:57.000 PM kernel[0]: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Wake - Full Wake/ Dark Wake / Maintenance wake
6/5/17 5:41:57.000 PM kernel[0]: Previous sleep cause: 5
6/5/17 5:41:57.000 PM kernel[0]: The USB device Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad (Port 6 of Hub at 0x4000000) may have caused a wake by issuing a remote wakeup (2)
6/5/17 5:41:57.000 PM kernel[0]: full wake promotion (reason 1) 303 ms
6/5/17 5:41:57.027 PM watchdogd[170]: [watchdog_daemon] @(         pm_callback) - ref=0x0 msg_type=0xe0000320 msg=0x0
6/5/17 5:41:57.000 PM kernel[0]: 00000000  00000020  NVEthernet::setLinkStatus - not Active
6/5/17 5:41:57.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: 802.11d country code set to 'X0'.
6/5/17 5:41:57.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: Supported channels 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64 100 104 108 112 116 120 124 128 132 136 140 149 153 157 161 165
6/5/17 5:41:57.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 1
6/5/17 5:41:57.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: 802.11d country code set to 'US'.
6/5/17 5:41:57.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: Supported channels 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64 100 104 108 112 116 120 124 128 132 136 140 149 153 157 161 165
6/5/17 5:41:57.547 PM WindowServer[132]: CGXDisplayDidWakeNotification [99782223377474]: posting kCGSDisplayDidWake
6/5/17 5:41:57.547 PM WindowServer[132]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: Ordering out authw 0x7fea69ce7d80(2000), shield 0x7fea69dafef0(2001) (lock state: 2)
6/5/17 5:41:57.548 PM WindowServer[132]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: errs 0x0, 0x0
6/5/17 5:41:57.546 PM loginwindow[85]: ERROR | -[LWBuiltInScreenLockAuthLion closeAuthAndReset:] | Attempted to remove an observer when not observing
```

FAN TURNS ON:

```
6/5/17 5:42:02.846 PM watchdogd[170]: [watchdog_daemon] @(         pm_callback) - ref=0x0 msg_type=0xe0000300 msg=0x0
6/5/17 5:42:02.848 PM sharingd[390]: 17:42:02.847 : Starting AirDrop server for user 501 on wake
6/5/17 5:42:02.850 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:42:02.849489 PM [AirPlay] Power: SystemHasPoweredOn
6/5/17 5:42:02.850 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:42:02.849644 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client starting to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
6/5/17 5:42:02.850 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:42:02.850170 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client stopping to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
6/5/17 5:42:02.850 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:42:02.850346 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client starting to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
6/5/17 5:42:02.853 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:42:02.853217 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client started to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
6/5/17 5:42:02.853 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:42:02.853438 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client stopped to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
6/5/17 5:42:02.854 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:42:02.853595 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client started to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
6/5/17 5:42:02.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 1
6/5/17 5:42:02.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 1
6/5/17 5:42:02.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 1
6/5/17 5:42:13.579 PM watchdogd[170]: [watchdog_daemon] @(         pm_callback) - ref=0x0 msg_type=0xe0000280 msg=0x2d2d0006
6/5/17 5:42:13.579 PM watchdogd[170]: [watchdog_daemon] @(    wd_daemon_thread) - events buffer: 99198r456273 99209s456273 99236r456621 99247s456621 99275r456976 99286s456976 99314r457364 99324s457364 99352r457732 99363s457732 99391r458070 99402s458070 99432r458411 99443s458411 99474r458768 99484s458768 99512r459115 99523s459115 99550r459450 99561s459450 99589r459894 99599s459894 99627r460243 99638s460243 99666r460601 99677s460601 99704r460955 99715s460955 99746r461311 99757s461311 99787r461676 99798s461676 
6/5/17 5:42:13.581 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:42:13.580972 PM [AirPlay] Power: SystemWillSleep
6/5/17 5:42:13.582 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:42:13.582406 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client stopping to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
6/5/17 5:42:13.584 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:42:13.584231 PM [AirPlay] BTLE discovery removing all devices
6/5/17 5:42:13.586 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:42:13.586432 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client stopped to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
6/5/17 5:42:15.709 PM WindowServer[132]: device_generate_desktop_screenshot: authw 0x7fea69ce7d80(2000), shield 0x7fea69dafef0(2001)
6/5/17 5:42:15.726 PM WindowServer[132]: device_generate_lock_screen_screenshot: authw 0x7fea69ce7d80(2000)[0, 0, 1280, 800] shield 0x7fea69dafef0(2001), dev [1280,800]
6/5/17 5:42:15.854 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.user.501) Service "com.apple.xpc.launchd.unmanaged.loginwindow.85" tried to hijack endpoint "com.apple.tsm.uiserver" from owner: com.apple.SystemUIServer.agent
6/5/17 5:42:15.854 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.user.501) Service "com.apple.xpc.launchd.unmanaged.loginwindow.85" tried to hijack endpoint "com.apple.tsm.uiserver" from owner: com.apple.SystemUIServer.agent
6/5/17 5:42:17.000 PM kernel[0]: PM response took 2777 ms (47, powerd)
6/5/17 5:42:17.000 PM kernel[0]: [0x9c4808000, 0x19000000]
6/5/17 5:42:17.000 PM kernel[0]: [0xa0c811000, 0x27000000]
6/5/17 5:42:17.000 PM kernel[0]: [0x0, 0x0]
6/5/17 5:42:17.000 PM kernel[0]: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Sleep 
6/5/17 5:42:17.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate image path: /var/vm/sleepimage
6/5/17 5:42:17.000 PM kernel[0]: efi pagecount 541
6/5/17 5:42:17.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall(preflight 1) start 0xffffff804c268000, 0xffffff804c369000
6/5/17 5:42:17.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall time: 110 ms
6/5/17 5:42:17.000 PM kernel[0]: pages 444041, wire 75996, act 157246, inact 27945, cleaned 1 spec 4, zf 27769, throt 0, compr 56403, xpmapped 28240
6/5/17 5:42:17.000 PM kernel[0]: could discard act 13905 inact 83428 purgeable 330 spec 989 cleaned 25
6/5/17 5:42:17.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall preflight pageCount 345364 est comp 61 setfile 934281216 min 1073741824
6/5/17 5:42:17.000 PM kernel[0]: [0x9c4808000, 0x19000000]
6/5/17 5:42:17.000 PM kernel[0]: [0xa0c811000, 0x27000000]
6/5/17 5:42:17.000 PM kernel[0]: [0x0, 0x0]
6/5/17 5:42:17.000 PM kernel[0]: kern_open_file_for_direct_io(0) took 0 ms
6/5/17 5:42:17.000 PM kernel[0]: Opened file /var/vm/sleepimage, size 1073741824, partition base 0x0, maxio 2000000 ssd 0
6/5/17 5:42:17.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate image major 1, minor 0, blocksize 4096, pollers 5
6/5/17 5:42:17.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_alloc_pages act 171415, inact 139234, anon 40661, throt 0, spec 994, wire 76258, wireinit 133356
6/5/17 5:42:17.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_setup(0) took 0 ms
6/5/17 5:42:17.000 PM kernel[0]: 00000000  00000020  NVEthernet::setLinkStatus - not Active
6/5/17 5:42:17.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 1
6/5/17 5:42:35.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall(preflight 0) start 0xffffff804c268000, 0xffffff804c369000
6/5/17 5:42:35.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall time: 115 ms
6/5/17 5:42:35.000 PM kernel[0]: pages 445789, wire 77724, act 157265, inact 27945, cleaned 2 spec 5, zf 27769, throt 0, compr 56403, xpmapped 28240
6/5/17 5:42:35.000 PM kernel[0]: could discard act 13905 inact 83428 purgeable 330 spec 989 cleaned 24
6/5/17 5:42:35.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall found pageCount 347113
6/5/17 5:42:35.000 PM kernel[0]: IOHibernatePollerOpen, ml_get_interrupts_enabled 0
6/5/17 5:42:35.000 PM kernel[0]: IOHibernatePollerOpen(0)
6/5/17 5:42:35.000 PM kernel[0]: encryptStart 14010
6/5/17 5:42:35.000 PM kernel[0]: bitmap_size 0xe048, previewSize 0x401000, writing 344835 pages @ 0x423058
6/5/17 5:42:35.000 PM kernel[0]: encryptEnd 50e4600
6/5/17 5:42:35.000 PM kernel[0]: image1Size 0x7d45000, encryptStart1 0x14010, End1 0x50e4600
6/5/17 5:42:35.000 PM kernel[0]: encryptStart 7d45000
6/5/17 5:42:35.000 PM kernel[0]: encryptEnd 34a49e00
6/5/17 5:42:35.000 PM kernel[0]: PMStats: Hibernate write took 16693 ms
6/5/17 5:42:35.000 PM kernel[0]: all time: 16693 ms, comp bytes: 1412726784 time: 2002 ms 672 Mb/s, crypt bytes: 836588528 time: 5716 ms 139 Mb/s, 
6/5/17 5:42:35.000 PM kernel[0]: image 883204096 (82%), uncompressed 1412726784 (344904), compressed 876320064 (62%), sum1 fb8b28fd, sum2 e03a9e0b
 6/5/17 5:42:35.000 PM kernel[0]: zeroPageCount 18359, wiredPagesEncrypted 48307, wiredPagesClear 27208, dirtyPagesEncrypted 269389
6/5/17 5:42:35.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_write_image done(0)
6/5/17 5:42:35.000 PM kernel[0]: sleep
6/5/17 5:42:35.000 PM kernel[0]: Wake reason: OHC1
6/5/17 5:42:35.409 PM loginwindow[85]: CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.
```

FAN TURNS OFF:

```
6/5/17 5:42:37.000 PM kernel[0]: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Wake - Full Wake/ Dark Wake / Maintenance wake
6/5/17 5:42:37.000 PM kernel[0]: Previous sleep cause: 5
6/5/17 5:42:37.000 PM kernel[0]: The USB device Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad (Port 6 of Hub at 0x4000000) may have caused a wake by issuing a remote wakeup (2)
6/5/17 5:42:37.000 PM kernel[0]: full wake promotion (reason 1) 302 ms
6/5/17 5:42:37.028 PM watchdogd[170]: [watchdog_daemon] @(         pm_callback) - ref=0x0 msg_type=0xe0000320 msg=0x0
6/5/17 5:42:37.000 PM kernel[0]: 00000000  00000020  NVEthernet::setLinkStatus - not Active
6/5/17 5:42:37.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: 802.11d country code set to 'X0'.
6/5/17 5:42:37.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: Supported channels 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64 100 104 108 112 116 120 124 128 132 136 140 149 153 157 161 165
6/5/17 5:42:37.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 1
6/5/17 5:42:37.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: 802.11d country code set to 'US'.
6/5/17 5:42:37.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: Supported channels 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64 100 104 108 112 116 120 124 128 132 136 140 149 153 157 161 165
6/5/17 5:42:37.544 PM WindowServer[132]: CGXDisplayDidWakeNotification [99820904954052]: posting kCGSDisplayDidWake
6/5/17 5:42:37.545 PM WindowServer[132]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: Ordering out authw 0x7fea69ce7d80(2000), shield 0x7fea69dafef0(2001) (lock state: 2)
6/5/17 5:42:37.546 PM WindowServer[132]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: errs 0x0, 0x0
6/5/17 5:42:37.546 PM loginwindow[85]: ERROR | -[LWBuiltInScreenLockAuthLion closeAuthAndReset:] | Attempted to remove an observer when not observing
```

FAN TURNS ON:

```
6/5/17 5:42:42.842 PM watchdogd[170]: [watchdog_daemon] @(         pm_callback) - ref=0x0 msg_type=0xe0000300 msg=0x0
6/5/17 5:42:42.845 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:42:42.844263 PM [AirPlay] Power: SystemHasPoweredOn
6/5/17 5:42:42.845 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:42:42.845325 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client starting to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
6/5/17 5:42:42.847 PM sharingd[390]: 17:42:42.847 : Starting AirDrop server for user 501 on wake
6/5/17 5:42:42.849 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:42:42.848893 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client stopping to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
6/5/17 5:42:42.850 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:42:42.850008 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client starting to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
6/5/17 5:42:42.850 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:42:42.850250 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client started to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
6/5/17 5:42:42.855 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:42:42.854573 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client stopped to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
6/5/17 5:42:42.855 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:42:42.854798 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client started to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
6/5/17 5:42:42.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 1
6/5/17 5:42:42.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 1
6/5/17 5:42:42.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 1
6/5/17 5:42:53.580 PM watchdogd[170]: [watchdog_daemon] @(         pm_callback) - ref=0x0 msg_type=0xe0000280 msg=0x2d3c0006
6/5/17 5:42:53.580 PM watchdogd[170]: [watchdog_daemon] @(    wd_daemon_thread) - events buffer: 99236r456621 99247s456621 99275r456976 99286s456976 99314r457364 99324s457364 99352r457732 99363s457732 99391r458070 99402s458070 99432r458411 99443s458411 99474r458768 99484s458768 99512r459115 99523s459115 99550r459450 99561s459450 99589r459894 99599s459894 99627r460243 99638s460243 99666r460601 99677s460601 99704r460955 99715s460955 99746r461311 99757s461311 99787r461676 99798s461676 99826r462025 99836s462025 
6/5/17 5:42:53.581 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:42:53.580755 PM [AirPlay] Power: SystemWillSleep
6/5/17 5:42:53.581 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:42:53.580900 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client stopping to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
6/5/17 5:42:53.581 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:42:53.581069 PM [AirPlay] BTLE discovery removing all devices
6/5/17 5:42:53.586 PM coreaudiod[198]: 2017-06-05 05:42:53.586159 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client stopped to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
6/5/17 5:42:55.711 PM WindowServer[132]: device_generate_desktop_screenshot: authw 0x7fea69cec9d0(2000), shield 0x7fea69ce7d80(2001)
6/5/17 5:42:55.727 PM WindowServer[132]: device_generate_lock_screen_screenshot: authw 0x7fea69cec9d0(2000)[0, 0, 1280, 800] shield 0x7fea69ce7d80(2001), dev [1280,800]
6/5/17 5:42:55.856 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.user.501) Service "com.apple.xpc.launchd.unmanaged.loginwindow.85" tried to hijack endpoint "com.apple.tsm.uiserver" from owner: com.apple.SystemUIServer.agent
6/5/17 5:42:55.856 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.user.501) Service "com.apple.xpc.launchd.unmanaged.loginwindow.85" tried to hijack endpoint "com.apple.tsm.uiserver" from owner: com.apple.SystemUIServer.agent
6/5/17 5:42:57.000 PM kernel[0]: PM response took 2677 ms (47, powerd)
6/5/17 5:42:57.000 PM kernel[0]: [0x9c4808000, 0x19000000]
6/5/17 5:42:57.000 PM kernel[0]: [0xa0c811000, 0x27000000]
6/5/17 5:42:57.000 PM kernel[0]: [0x0, 0x0]
6/5/17 5:42:57.000 PM kernel[0]: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Sleep 
6/5/17 5:42:57.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate image path: /var/vm/sleepimage
6/5/17 5:42:57.000 PM kernel[0]: efi pagecount 541
6/5/17 5:42:57.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall(preflight 1) start 0xffffff804c268000, 0xffffff804c369000
6/5/17 5:42:57.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall time: 110 ms
6/5/17 5:42:57.000 PM kernel[0]: pages 444142, wire 76024, act 157271, inact 27945, cleaned 1 spec 4, zf 27768, throt 0, compr 56403, xpmapped 28240
6/5/17 5:42:57.000 PM kernel[0]: could discard act 13918 inact 83438 purgeable 338 spec 1007 cleaned 25
6/5/17 5:42:57.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall preflight pageCount 345416 est comp 61 setfile 934281216 min 1073741824
6/5/17 5:42:57.000 PM kernel[0]: [0x9c4808000, 0x19000000]
6/5/17 5:42:57.000 PM kernel[0]: [0xa0c811000, 0x27000000]
6/5/17 5:42:57.000 PM kernel[0]: [0x0, 0x0]
6/5/17 5:42:57.000 PM kernel[0]: kern_open_file_for_direct_io(0) took 0 ms
6/5/17 5:42:57.000 PM kernel[0]: Opened file /var/vm/sleepimage, size 1073741824, partition base 0x0, maxio 2000000 ssd 0
6/5/17 5:42:57.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate image major 1, minor 0, blocksize 4096, pollers 5
6/5/17 5:42:57.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_alloc_pages act 171461, inact 139245, anon 40661, throt 0, spec 1011, wire 76259, wireinit 133356
6/5/17 5:42:57.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_setup(0) took 0 ms
6/5/17 5:42:57.000 PM kernel[0]: 00000000  00000020  NVEthernet::setLinkStatus - not Active
6/5/17 5:42:57.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 1
```

FAN TURNS OFF:

```
6/5/17 5:43:18.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall(preflight 0) start 0xffffff804c268000, 0xffffff804c369000
6/5/17 5:43:18.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall time: 116 ms
6/5/17 5:43:18.000 PM kernel[0]: pages 445864, wire 77725, act 157290, inact 27947, cleaned 2 spec 4, zf 27768, throt 0, compr 56403, xpmapped 28240
6/5/17 5:43:18.000 PM kernel[0]: could discard act 13918 inact 83438 purgeable 338 spec 1007 cleaned 24
6/5/17 5:43:18.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall found pageCount 347139
6/5/17 5:43:18.000 PM kernel[0]: IOHibernatePollerOpen, ml_get_interrupts_enabled 0
6/5/17 5:43:18.000 PM kernel[0]: IOHibernatePollerOpen(0)
6/5/17 5:43:18.000 PM kernel[0]: encryptStart 14010
6/5/17 5:43:18.000 PM kernel[0]: bitmap_size 0xe048, previewSize 0x401000, writing 344861 pages @ 0x423058
6/5/17 5:43:18.000 PM kernel[0]: encryptEnd 510e600
6/5/17 5:43:18.000 PM kernel[0]: image1Size 0x7d70000, encryptStart1 0x14010, End1 0x510e600
6/5/17 5:43:18.000 PM kernel[0]: encryptStart 7d70000
6/5/17 5:43:18.000 PM kernel[0]: encryptEnd 34a43e00
6/5/17 5:43:18.000 PM kernel[0]: PMStats: Hibernate write took 19402 ms
6/5/17 5:43:18.000 PM kernel[0]: all time: 19402 ms, comp bytes: 1412833280 time: 2003 ms 672 Mb/s, crypt bytes: 836559856 time: 5715 ms 139 Mb/s, 
6/5/17 5:43:18.000 PM kernel[0]: image 883179520 (82%), uncompressed 1412833280 (344930), compressed 876294656 (62%), sum1 d0475ea8, sum2 7b2b7f48
6/5/17 5:43:18.000 PM kernel[0]: zeroPageCount 18368, wiredPagesEncrypted 48308, wiredPagesClear 27208, dirtyPagesEncrypted 269414
6/5/17 5:43:18.000 PM kernel[0]: hibernate_write_image done(0)
6/5/17 5:43:18.000 PM kernel[0]: sleep
6/5/17 5:43:18.000 PM kernel[0]: Wake reason: OHC1
6/5/17 5:43:18.034 PM loginwindow[85]: CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.
6/5/17 5:43:19.000 PM kernel[0]: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Wake - Full Wake/ Dark Wake / Maintenance wake
6/5/17 5:43:19.000 PM kernel[0]: Previous sleep cause: 5
6/5/17 5:43:19.000 PM kernel[0]: The USB device Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad (Port 6 of Hub at 0x4000000) may have caused a wake by issuing a remote wakeup (2)
6/5/17 5:43:19.000 PM kernel[0]: full wake promotion (reason 1) 304 ms
6/5/17 5:43:19.029 PM watchdogd[170]: [watchdog_daemon] @(         pm_callback) - ref=0x0 msg_type=0xe0000320 msg=0x0
6/5/17 5:43:19.000 PM kernel[0]: 00000000  00000020  NVEthernet::setLinkStatus - not Active
6/5/17 5:43:19.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: 802.11d country code set to 'X0'.
6/5/17 5:43:19.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: Supported channels 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64 100 104 108 112 116 120 124 128 132 136 140 149 153 157 161 165
6/5/17 5:43:19.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 1
6/5/17 5:43:19.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: 802.11d country code set to 'US'.
6/5/17 5:43:19.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: Supported channels 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64 100 104 108 112 116 120 124 128 132 136 140 149 153 157 161 165
6/5/17 5:43:19.547 PM WindowServer[132]: CGXDisplayDidWakeNotification [99862211494533]: posting kCGSDisplayDidWake
6/5/17 5:43:19.548 PM WindowServer[132]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: Ordering out authw 0x7fea69cec9d0(2000), shield 0x7fea69ce7d80(2001) (lock state: 2)
6/5/17 5:43:19.548 PM WindowServer[132]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: errs 0x0, 0x0
6/5/17 5:43:19.546 PM loginwindow[85]: ERROR | -[LWBuiltInScreenLockAuthLion closeAuthAndReset:] | Attempted to remove an observer when not observing
```

And so it goes...

Comment: Some questions for you: (1) Do you also observe this behaviour while the computer is not asleep? (2) Do you have any audio bluetooth devices paired to the Mac? (3) What settings do you have set in your Energy Saver preferences? (4) What exact model of 2009 MacBook do you own? If you're not sure, is it one you can remove the battery from or not?

Comment: Try running [AHT](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201257)... seems as though other users have had the wake reason 0HC1. Some think it’s a keyboard wake issue.

Comment: Monomeeth, sometimes this does happen when the computer is not sleeping. I do not have any bluetooth devices paired with the mac. In terms of settings, for "battery" I have the computer set to sleep after 10 minutes, the display to sleep after 5, and both boxes checked for 'Put hard disks to sleep when possible' and 'Slightly dim the display while on battery power.' For "Power Adapter", both Computer and Display sleep are set to 10 minutes and both boxes are checked for 'Put hard disks to sleep when possible' and 'Wake for network access'. My Macbook is the "Macbook 6,1" (late 2009).

Comment: Bret7600, I tried running AHT (Holding down either just D or Alt+D) and it did not work. Apparently some models require that a disk be used, but I got rid of my disks a long time ago! Bummer.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer your main question about the fans.

On most/all Mac laptops, the fans pull air *through holes for the keys in the built-in keyboard,* so you should expect different fan behavior with the clamshell closed. Most/all vents are near the hinge, away from the user. The fans blow air out of the case through those vents. If you ever open a Mac's laptop case, you will see each fan's circular inlet under the keyboard and its outlet channeled to a vent near the hinge.

For maximum cooling, the fans circulate air in-and-out the laptop. By basic physics (conservation of matter), the air leaving the case must be replaced with air entering the case. Each fan's inlet creates a slight vacuum to pull in air. That incoming air comes from the various holes:

- in the keyboard
- various physical ports (USB, ethernet, audio line-in, headphone out);
- optical drive slot; and
- the Kensington security slat.

Thus, with the clamshell closed, the fans will work harder to pull air through the keyboard's holes.

You have also connected a USB keyboard. Plugging a keyboard connector into a USB slot will also slightly restrict airflow. Plugging in the keyboard will have a greater effect on airflow a closed clamshell because the top/display restricts airflow through the keyboard.

But, your laptop will work different circuits with the clamshell closed. Normally, closing the clamshell will turn-off the built-in video, so the circuits for the built-in video will shut-off. The laptop may also turn-on another different graphics processing unit [GPU] whenever the laptop connects an external monitor. For my Late-2011 MacBook Pro [MBP], simply connecting an external monitor, regardless whether the clamshell is closed, engages a separate high-performance dedicated/discrete GPU [dGPU]. Further, your external USB keyboard's switch matrix replaces your built-in keyboard's switch matrix.

For, some Macs, but perhaps not your MacBook, Energy Saver's preferences permit "automatic graphics switching [AGS] between a standard/integrated graphics processing unit [GPU] and a high-performance dedicated/discrete GPU [dGPU]," so "your computer will automatically switch between graphics modes for better battery life." 
[image: OS X Sierra Energy Preferences Automatic Graphics Switching]
In theory, the specialized high-performance dGPU more efficiently processes graphics information in the general CPU.

At least in OS X Sierra 10.12, Activity Monitor's Energy tab shows the active graphics processor as "Graphics Card" at the bottom of the window. 
[image: OS X 10.12 Sierra Activity Monitor Energy Tab Redacted]
The Energy tab also shows whether each listed application requires the high performance GPU.

To *lower* temperature, I have checked AGS to *prevent* engaging my Late-2011 MBP's dGPU for low-level applications. For instance, Safari does *not* need the dGPU, but Opera, Chrome, and maybe Firefox can demand the dGPU.

By feel, my Late-2011 MBP, with an AMD Radeon HD 6770M dGPU mostly runs much hotter with automatic graphics switching while disconnected from the MagSafe adapter. Alas, that was before early November 2018 when I got real time temperature monitoring with the formerly-free Max Fan Control v. 1.4.2, so I do not have precise temperature measurements. (Also, connecting an external monitor automatically engages the Radeon HD 6770M dGPU and greatly increases its temperature before or while causing the dGPU to fail. In "Radeongate" Apple recalled a few years of MBPs for defective AMD Radeon dGPUs. A full discussion of "Radeongate" is for another time.)

Tech Tool Pro 9's Sensor Check also shows temperature data. But it only shows *all* sensor date, not just for the temperature sensors. Sensor Check does not continuously update the sensor data, so the user must repeatedly run sensor check. Micromat has issued Tech Tool Pro 10 in the past year.

Comment: *Conservation of matter?*  It not a chemical reaction.  Maybe you're thinking about the laws of thermodynamics and pressure equilibrium?  Additionally, I don't see where you actually answer the question asked by the OP....